# Draw states in mapControl

Tags: winrt-xaml

I'm writing an application for windows Phone and I'm using a MapControl.
I'd like to be able to paint the US States in different colors.
For example, CA in Red, NV in blue, etc

I Thought about doing Shapes and Polilines, but I can't find the coordinates to use in the shapes to get the different States.

I also tried using the

```
var found = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync("California", new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()));
```

but it doesn't work for finding States.

Comment: If you were able to find the shape data for each of the states, I would use a MapPolygon to render each one and set the colors accordingly. The hard part there is finding the shape data and then writing the code to parse it into a list of geopoints. (Adding it to the MapControl as a MapPolyline would be the easy part).

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to download GeoJSON files from this public repository

https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries/USA

Parse the JSON and Create MapPolygon object and add it to map.

```
 public async void RenderState() {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response=await client.GetAsync(new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries/USA/CO.geo.json"));
        string json=response.Content.ToString();
        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        JObject poly = (JObject)obj["features"][0]["geometry"];
        JArray coords = (JArray)poly["coordinates"][0];
        MapPolygon polygon = new MapPolygon();
        List<BasicGeoposition> points = new List<BasicGeoposition>();
        foreach (JArray arr in coords) {
            points.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = (double)arr[1], Longitude = (double)arr[0] });
        }

        //Remove last point as it is a duplicate
        if (points.Count > 1) {
            points.RemoveAt(points.Count - 1);
        }
        polygon.Path = new Geopath(points);
        polygon.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        polygon.FillColor = Colors.Blue;
        this.mMap.MapElements.Add(polygon);


    }
```

This code will render the state of colarado